# How to check file type for an image stored as url?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I have a list of urls which look more or less like this:

```
'https://myurl.com/images/avatars/cb55-f14b-455d1-9ac4w20190416075520341'
```

I'm trying to validate the image behind the url and check what image type (png, jpeg or other) it has and write back the image type into a new dataframe column imgType.

my code so far

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/allLogo.csv')
urls = df.T.values.tolist()[4]

for x in urls:
#i'm stuck here... as the content doesn't seem to give me image type.
s=requests.get(url, verify=False).content


df["imgType"] =
df.to_csv('mypath/output.csv')
```

Could someone help me with this? thanks in advance

Comment: This is an issue that is dependent on how the website renders the image on the screen (whether it does so via iFrame, img tags, etc. etc. etc.). If you could post a working URL, it would help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to check response headers for `'Content-Type'` - but it depends on the server what headers are sent back to the client (without knowing the real URL is hard to tell):

```
import requests

url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_right_darkblue_121621.png'

response = requests.get(url)

# uncomment this to print all response headers:
# print(response.headers)

print(response.headers['Content-Type'])
```

Prints:

```
image/png
```

Answer (score 0):

*check what image type (png, jpeg or other)*

If you manage to download it, either to disk (file) or memory (as bytes - `.content` of `requests`' response) then you might harness python built-in module [imghdr](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/imghdr.html), following way:

```
import imghdr
imgtype = imghdr.what("path/to/image.png")  # testing file on disk
```

or

```
import requests
r = requests.get("url_of_image")
imgtype = imghdr.what(h=r.content)  # testing
```

Keep in mind that `imghdr` does recognize limited set of image file format (see linked docs), however it should suffice if you are only interested in detecting `png` vs `jpeg` vs other.